# proc/stat idle time decreasing

Tags: java, android

I have written some code to calculate cpu load on android devices by reading the first line in proc/stat which works fine most of the time except it returns a negative value now and again, upon further inspection i realized that the idle time value decreases sometimes, i created a dummy runnable class to demonstrate this behaviour:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    String[]cpuTimeInfo;
    long idle2;
    long idle1;
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (new File("/proc/stat").exists()) {

            try{
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/stat")));
                String aLine;

                while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null){

                    if(aLine.substring(0, 3).equals("cpu")){

                        cpuTimeInfo = aLine.split("\\s+");
                        idle1 = Long.parseLong(cpuTimeInfo[4]);;

                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/stat")));
                            aLine = br.readLine();
                            cpuTimeInfo = aLine.split("\\s+");
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException e){

                        }

                        idle2 = Long.parseLong(cpuTimeInfo[4]);;
                        if(idle2 < idle1)
                            Log.d("????", "Idle 1: " + idle1 + " Idle 2: " + idle2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e){
            }
        }
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

}
```

1. Can someone please explain to me how is this possible.
2. Is there a proper workaround or real solution to this problem

Comment: Not solving the problem but instead of `Thread.sleep(1000)` you can use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L)`; also, you `.split("\\s+")` often: create a `private static fnal Pattern SPACES = Pattern.compile("\\s+")` and use `SPACES.split()`. And finally, use an `ExecutorService` instead of a `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on android devices. What I figured was that the value in the idle column is not actually decreasing over time but is lower by a third to what it used to be from time to time. My wild guess is that it has something to do with the aggregate of  each CPU core values.

However I don't know how to fix the problem. Maybe we'll have to get the values for each core and do the addition ourselves. Don't know, I haven't gone that far yet and I deem this overly unconstructive.

The workaround is actually quite simple: update an idle variable for every idleX obtained. If the new value is lower than idle then skip the loop iteration. Simply said it means to skip any case where the idle is not going crescending.

Here are a few traces that illustrate well the problem at hand. It is a dump of the first line of /proc/stat at regular interval. Look at the 5th column, i.e. the one that goes from about 7M (wrong) to 10M (correct).

```
Wed Mar 18 11:40:25 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 392408 78027 265140 10190657 28775 74 3969 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:40:31 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 392602 78031 265285 10195990 28794 74 3974 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:40:37 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 392731 78049 265399 10197540 28804 74 3988 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:40:43 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 392882 78058 265521 7938411 28655 74 4017 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:40:49 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 392956 78058 265636 10199960 28827 74 4029 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:40:55 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 393032 78058 265720 10201160 28836 74 4030 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:41:01 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 393159 78059 265809 7941553 28668 74 4030 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:41:07 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 393316 78070 265917 7942154 28679 74 4038 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:41:13 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 393441 78085 266048 7943935 28691 75 4054 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:41:19 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 393614 78086 266206 7950457 28704 75 4086 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:41:26 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 393716 78086 266295 10213601 28875 75 4087 0 0 0]
Wed Mar 18 11:41:32 CET 2015,INFO,cpu: getSystemCpuUsage start=[cpu 393812 78086 266372 10214027 28875 75 4087 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, i am storing the idle time in a variable and skipping the loop when the new idle time is lower than the previous and i think this is good enough, and i agree, this is is a waste of time trying to figure this out